# Ursprung von "holzseelig"

Tags: etymology

Was bedeutet das Wort "holzseelig" und woher stammt es? Wird es heutzutage noch ab und zu verwendet?

Eine Google-Suche ergibt nur 5 Resultate, hier eines davon in einem alten Text:

> *»... daß sich das **holzseelig** Verslein nirgends finde, als in einer einzigen Bibel Lutheri, ...«*
>
> aus [Keines von Beyden, Herr Weißlinger!](https://books.google.de/books?id=iS9OAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA877&lpg=PA877&dq=%22holzseelig%22&source=bl&ots=kgrsX4mK8r&sig=BLoL_sxklskWQImdHKx8AeK_FfE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJjci-4tvWAhXIKVAKHQjZCGMQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22holzseelig%22&f=false)
>   von Johann Caspar Malschen
>   Anno 1732

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Man kennt zwar noch heute eine "hölzerne Seele" als Ausdruck für eine gleichgültige, wenig empathische Person, ich denke aber in diesem und in weiteren wenigen Zitaten, die ich bei Google Books gefunden habe passt das nicht zum Kontext. Es wird gesprochen von

> - Mutterschaft, so schön, und **holzseelig** man sie mir immer vormahle...
> - von den Griechen *Charis*, das ist liebseelig das **holzseelig** Salz ...
> - als schönste Gesätzlein hat hören lassen, dermassen **holzseelig** singend,...

also immer von einer sehr postitiven, beseelten Eigenschaft.

Deshalb denke ich, dass es sich um eine etwas eigenartige Schreibweise von [**holdselig**](https://www.dwds.de/wb/holdselig) handelt, ein weitaus gebräuchlicheres Wort das offenbar gleich ausgesprochen wurde. Es gabe damals noch kein Duden und keine festen Rechtschreibregeln.

Die Bedeutungen von *holdselig* (liebreizend, anmutig) passen wunderbar zu den oben genannten Zitaten.

Comment: Das denke ich auch - Im Grimm finden sich Schreibweisen von *holdseelig* über *holtsälig" bis *holdtseelig", so dass das gut sein kann. Ein paar der Fundstellen in Google Books sind zumindestens nach einer groben Stichprobenuntersuchung nichtmal originale Schreibfehler, sondern möglicherweise Fehlinterpretationen der OCR-Software.

Comment: @mare Zu der guten Antwort noch die Ergänzung, dass auch holdselig in der heutigen Sprache nicht üblich ist.

Comment: @Philipp: ganz richtig. Der Worthäufigkeitsplot im Link zu DWDS zeigt, dass die Benutzung seit dem 17. Jahrhundert stetig rückläufig ist. Es finden sich aber im Textkorpus immerhin auch noch neuere Fundstellen. Ganz weg ist *holdselig* also noch nicht.

Answer (score 1):

*Holdseelig* sind die junge Maiden,
für die die Freier sich verleiden.
 
*Holzseelig* ist jedoch nur einer:
 
der seinem Handwerk zugetane Schreiner,
der liebevoll sein Brettchen sägt,
seit Gernhard diesen Vers geprägt:
"Schaut, wie flink und frettchenhaft
er an seinem Brettchen schafft."